# Loading locals onto stack for method call in IL generation?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, il

I'm trying to generate IL to mimic the following method `MyMethod`:

```
public void DoSomething(object a, object b, string c, string d){...};
public virtual void MyMethod(object a, object b) 
{
    DoSomething(a, b, "hello", this.SomeInstanceString);
}
```

This is what I've got so far, but I'm unable to understand the proper way to load the 3rd and 4th arguments onto the stack to call `DoSomething(a, b, "hello", this.SomeInstanceString))`:

```
 MethodBuilder myMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("MyMethod",
    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(void), new[] 
       { typeof(object), typeof(object) });
 ILGenerator myMethodILGen = mbFromCustomObject.GetILGenerator();
 myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
 myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
 // How do I load the string "hello" and the local instance 
 // variable this.SomeInstanceString onto the stack?
 myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetMethodInfoForDoSomething());
 myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

So, how do I load the string `"hello"` and the local instance variable `this.SomeInstanceString` onto the stack to call `DoSomething`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading a string literal is fairly easy.

```
myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "hello");
```

Loading a field from the object instance requires that you first load the object instance onto the stack and then use the Ldfld opcode. You should presumably have a FieldBuilder for your SomeInstanceString field already that you can use for this.

```
FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(
                    "SomeInstanceString",
                    typeof(string),
                    FieldAttributes.Public);

myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
myMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
```

Also, keep in mind that Ldarg_0 *does not do what you think it does*. Instance methods have an implicit argument that is in the zero slot which contains the instance that the method is currently operating within. That's why we're using Ldarg_0 to dereference the field, because presumably you want the instance that the method is in. This does not apply to static methods, though.

Comment: Yes, I have a field builder actually. I was looking at the IL in IL DASM and sure enough you're right on the money.

Comment: @Mike Good to hear. Ildasm will be very useful to you. I'd also recommend PEVerify to make sure that the resulting assembly is in a good format.

Comment: PEVerify took me the last mile to fix something else broken in my IL generation. Thanks a bunch, this was very helpful.